# Postgres CREATE TABLE AS SELECT with unknown column type

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, create-table

I want to create a table with the following query:

```
create table something as
select 
      other_id, 
      other_title, 
      '0.0.0.0' as IP, 
      1 as used 
from
      other_table
```

But Postgres complains that:

> ```
> column "ip" has type "unknown"
> ```

How can I specify it to be of type `char`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast your column, like this:

```
'0.0.0.0'::INET as IP,
```

Comment: Or ::text if you don't want to handle it as an real IP

Answer (score 1):

At least since **Postgres 9.4**, this does not raise an `EXCEPTION`, just a `WARNING`. The table is created anyway, with a column of data type `unknown` if no type is given for the string literal:

*dbfiddle for pg 9.4 [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=10818f2614ca40864e26d11fd6ef3e98)*

**Postgres 10** introduces more useful default behavior. String literals are cast to the default data type `text` unless cast explicitly. So you don't get columns of type `unknown` any more:

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=10818f2614ca40864e26d11fd6ef3e98)*

Introduced with [this commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=1e7c4bb0049732ece651d993d03bb6772e5d281a) (with detailed explanation).

And the type `unknown` has been labeled a pseudo-type now. [Details in this commit.](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=d8d32d9a56a3cecfb14e8f47ebd50b780edffe60)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the type , use '0.0.0.0'::text AS IP